# How to use a data type contains function

Tags: haskell

I have following data type definition:

```
newtype Combine a b = 
  Combine { unCombine :: a -> b }
```

and then I can defined as follow:

```
Prelude> let f = Combine $ \n -> Sum (n + 1)
```

My question is, how to use `f`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> unCombine f 1
Sum {getSum = 2}
Prelude Data.Monoid> unCombine f 42
Sum {getSum = 43}
```